# Как подсчитать количество строк по ключу ? postgresql и sqlachemy на Flask

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Подскажите можно ли это сделать? Мне надо получить количество строк по ключу и вывести их на html. Есть таблица с клиентами, в ней есть id а в другой данные и указано к какому клиенту относится(по id). у меня есть код который выводит все из бд но мне надо каждому клиенту поставить количество значений.

Вот часть кода html:

```html
{% for el in customers %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ el.surname }}</td>
  <td>{{ el.name }}</td>
  <td>???</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

часть кода viems.py:

```
@app.route('/customer', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def cust():
    customers = Customer.query.order_by(Customer.surname).all()
    return render_template('customer.html', customers=customers, data=data)
```

и сама модель:

```
class Customer(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'customer'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    surname = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    egu_1 = db.relationship('Equipment_accounting', backref='customer', lazy=True)


class Equipment_accounting(db.Model):
    __tablename__ ='equipment_accounting'
    id_equipment_accounting = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DATETIME, default=datetime.utcnow)
    model = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    serial_number = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    client_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('customer.id'), nullable=False)
```

Получаеться в Customer id клиентов а в Equipment_accounting все данные которые связанные с ними, и мне надо просто количество относящемуся к id

Comment: *мне надо просто количество относящемуся к id* Группировка по юзеру с подсчётом количества записей (GROUP BY и COUNT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это простая задача на группировку данных.

Для начала нужно объединить 2 таблицы Customer и Equipment_accounting методом [**join**](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.join) , а потом [**сгруппировать**](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.group_by) вместе с оператором count(Customer.id)

На подобный вопрос ответили [*тут*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052148/group-by-count-function-in-sqlalchemy)

Comment: я из вывел но не могу подсчитать, использовал : SELECT  customer.id, customer.surname FROM customer JOIN equipment_accounting ON customer.id = equipment_accounting.client_id

Comment: SELECT customer.id, COUNT(*) FROM (customer JOIN equipment_accounting ON customer.id = equipment_accounting.client_id) GROUP BY customer.id;

Comment: спасибо, осталось как то в sqlAlchemy засунуть

Comment: Попробуй так:

result= db.query(
                Customer.id, 
                func.count(Customer.id).label("total_counts")
            ).join(
                Equipment_accounting, Customer.id
            ).group_by(
                Customer.id
            ).all()

Comment: result = db.query(Customer.id, func.count(Customer.id).label("total_counts")).join(Equipment_accounting).group_by(
AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'query', Есть разница в том что я использую flask_sqlalchemy ? просто func есть sqlachemy

Comment: так, у вас переменная db не сессия. сделайте запрос к сессии

Comment: получилось, осталось тока от туда их взять ?

Comment: Так если вы пользуетесь `Table.query` методом запроса, то вместо db нужно ставить Customer
`result = Customer.query(Customer.id, func.count(Customer.id).label("total_counts")).join(Equipment_accounting).group_by(Customer.id).all()`

Comment: Тогда ошибка, TypeError: 'BaseQuery' object is not callable

Comment: тогда все же лучше перейти на использование `db.session.query(...)`
Вот дока https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html
попробуйте открыть сессию так как предложено там

Comment: попробуйте это сделать вот [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40020388/flask-sqlalchemy-db-session-querymodel-vs-model-query)

Comment: Все бы хорошо, я + - понимаю но не могу понять как вывести их на html не ломая мой код (

Comment: Так у тебя же с запроса возвращается не вся таблица, а только 2 поля. `print(customers)` скинь

Comment: [<Customer 21>, <Customer 18>, <Customer 22>, <Customer 25>] 

[(21, 'Float', 1), (18, 'Kirgman', 2), (22, 'Xrabrix', 2)] а это уже ссесия